# Filter output from table based on cell, but search for cell value through multiple columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a formula that will return columns from a table to me based on the value I select in cell C2:
 `=FILTER(INDEX(Initiatives, SEQUENCE(ROWS(Initiatives)), XMATCH(B6:G6, Initiatives[#Headers])), Initiatives[Lead]=C2, "Nothing Found")`

This is working as anticipated and correctly as it is only looking for the value in C2 in one column in the Initiatives table which is the "Lead" column.

Below is the source table from which I want to call the data, so looking at this table, I want to be able to search for the value in cell C2 in all of the support columns

| Topic | Initiative | Status | Priority | Resourced? | Lead | Support 1 | Support 2 | Support 3 | Support 4 | Support 5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| X | Intiatiative Description 1 | X | X | Yes | Team Member 5 | Team Member 5 | Team Member 7 | Team Member 16 | Team Member 5 | Team Member 17 |
| X | Intiatiative Description 2 | X | X | Yes | Team Member 35 | Team Member 42 | Team Member 22 | Team Member 7 | Team Member 24 | Team Member 5 |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

I now want to have a separate output that will generate a list based on whether or not the value of cell C2 appears in ANY of the columns of Support 1, Support 2, Support 3, Support 4, Support 5 or Support 6.

Many thanks in advance!

I initially thought I could alter the existing formula to something like:

`=FILTER(INDEX(Initiatives, SEQUENCE(ROWS(Initiatives)), XMATCH(B6:G6, Initiatives[#Headers])), Initiatives[@[Support 1]:[Support 6]], "Nothing Found")`

...but this does not work and results in #VALUE :(

I was wondering if anyone would be able to help with this and let me know if there is a way to search through multiple columns (that are adjacent) with this function?

Comment: Can you provide some sample data - best by using [Markdown Table Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) (read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/16578424) for an explanation)

Comment: @Ike Hi Ike, thank you for your response, I have now added in some sample data! (Thank you for linking the explanation, very kind)

Comment: In the sample data provided, “Initiative 1” has “Member 5” listed as the Lead, Support 1 and Support 4. So, one person can be the lead and have multiple support roles? Should the end result be showing only the “Initiatives” where the “Member” in C2 had one or more support roles, _AND_ only the “Support” columns where their name was found? Also, what version of Excel are you using? I’ve watched that video you referred to in the comments before, and I have some ideas, but an appropriate solution will depend on what version you have.

Answer (score 2):

Try this formula:

```vb
=LET(isSupport,BYROW(Initiatives[[Support 1]:[Support 5]],LAMBDA(r,COUNTIF(r,$C$2)>0)),
FILTER(Initiatives[[Initiative]:[Lead]],isSupport = TRUE))
```

Although I don't understand why you use `INDEX` within the `FILTER` function

Comment: Thanks for your response Ike, I have the index function in case I want to change which rows are being output simply by changing the output table header rows. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2jxS_0qQHlA I used this video :)

I have tried your formula but I'm afraid it hasn't worked, this is my first time using the LAMBDA function, what does the 'r' refer to?

Comment: What Excel version do you have? What is the result of the formula? I suppose you mean, you want to set the **columns** that are output - not the **rows** ... but for that you don't need the index construct ... In this case `Lambda` is the function that is calculated per row --> `r` is the row from the `Initiatives[[Support 1]:[Support 5]]` array

Answer (score 0):

**METHOD 1 (compatible with Excel 2021):**

Add a new column to your "*Initiatives*" table called "***Supporting Roles***" and use the following formula to make it a calculated column:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ", TRUE, RIGHT(FILTER(Initiatives[[#Headers],[Support 1]:[Support 6]], Initiatives[@[Support 1]:[Support 6]]=Report!$C$2, ""), 1))
```

**NOTE:** if the *ACTUAL* column names in your table are not "*Support 1*" thru to "*Support 6*", but rather the names of the various roles (ie: "Marketing", "Fundraising", etc."), then remove the `RIGHT()` function from the formula above and be sure to adjust the range for the support columns accordingly. For example, if the first support column is "*Marketing*" and the last column is "*Logistics*", then use:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ", TRUE, FILTER(Initiatives[[#Headers],[Marketing]:[Logistics]], Initiatives[@[Marketing]:[Logistics]]=Report!$C$2, ""))
```

**ALSO:** in my example, the cell to filter the table by "*Member*" is located on the sheet named "*Report*" in cell `C2`, so be sure to change `Report!$C$2` in the above formulas to match your setup.

[image: data_table.png]

**LASTLY:** on the "*Report*" sheet, enter the column headers to be returned in range `I6:N6`, then use the following formula in cell `I7` to filter by "*Supporting Roles*" for the member selected in cell `C2`:

```
=FILTER(INDEX(Initiatives, SEQUENCE(ROWS(Initiatives)), XMATCH(I6:N6, Initiatives[#Headers])), Initiatives[Supporting Roles]<>"", "Nothing Found")
```

[image: method_2021.png]

**METHOD 2 (for MS365 only):**

If you have Excel for Microsoft 365, you don't need to add the "*Supporting Roles*" column to the "*Initiatives*" table, as demonstrated in Method 1 above. Everything can be calculated and output using a single formula with the `LET()` function:

```
=LET(
suppRoles, BYROW(Initiatives[[Support 1]:[Support 6]], LAMBDA(r,
   TEXTJOIN(", ", TRUE, RIGHT(FILTER(Initiatives[[#Headers],[Support 1]:[Support 6]], r=C2, ""), 1)))),
arr, HSTACK(CHOOSECOLS(Initiatives, XMATCH(I6:M6, Initiatives[#Headers])), suppRoles),
FILTER(arr, suppRoles<>"", "Nothing Found"))
```

**NOTE:** since the "*Supporting Roles*" column does not exist in this case, be sure to exclude it from the *lookup_value* range used in `XMATCH()`.

[image: method_365.png]

**ALSO:** the method to dynamically select the columns was simplified from this...

```
=INDEX(Initiatives, SEQUENCE(ROWS(Initiatives)), XMATCH(I6:M6, Initiatives[#Headers]))
```

...to this...

```
=CHOOSECOLS(Initiatives, XMATCH(I6:M6, Initiatives[#Headers]))
```

The `INDEX() + SEQUENCE() + ROWS()` method is no longer needed, as `CHOOSECOLS()` will get the job done.

Cheers!